# Why instead of using the static void main method, it use the non static method

Tags: java, static, program-entry-point, non-static

Why the below snippet code use a non-static to run the program??? It there the advantages of running the program in that style???

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main go = new Main();
    go.start();

}

public Main() {

}

public void start() {
    //SOME CODE HERE

}
```

Comment: public Main()  in this case is a constructor, not a method.

Comment: It is using static method - the first one executed is public static void main(String[] args) then - inside this method - object "Main" is created and then non-static method start() is executed.

Comment: This programm still uses the static `main` method as its entry point. It just creates an instance of the class `Main` and then calls a method on it. You could also call this class `Foo` and the method `bar` or `Peter` and `parker`. This does not change anything. The entry point is always the `main` method. Why is it done this way? It's quite nasty to have a lot of logic in a `main` method. Hard to test, hard to work with.

Comment: Just want to ask why the code wanted to execute in the start() method but not the static void main(). Is there some different???

Comment: @HuatLee have a look at the answer by GhostCat which as usual explains a lot of things in a nice and comprehensible manner. Other than that you can also have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302110/java-how-much-logic-to-put-in-the-main-class) with some more input.

Comment: Ok! Thanks alot guys !

Comment: `Just want to ask why the code wanted to execute in the start() method` Is this a Java applet?

Answer (score 5):

Basically, there are two advantages of having a `main()` that simply instantiates an instance of the corresponding class, to then call methods on that object:

- it allows you to "re-use" that Main class in a more object oriented way. If *another* class wants to use `Main`, calling a static method to get that going is most often not what you want (it makes unit testing harder for example to use static methods). Therefore, if "re-use" is one of your requirements, then making it possible to instantiate that class, and using it without calling its static `main()` can be beneficial.
- beyond that, it **also** makes it a bit easier to unit test the main class as well.

Comment: Maybe change the wording of "The one advantage" which (to me atleast) kinda implies that it's not really a good thing to do. Like "well, it's not a good thing but I guess the one advantage is..."

Answer (score 2):

Classic object-oriented approach encourages encapsulation: everything must be local as much as possible and multiple instances of the class must be possible. Global is bad and ugly.

Object-oriented approach also encourages inheritance, polymorphism and possibility to override methods with well defined functionality. Or, alternatively, composition (compose alternative versions of the complex object from well defined sub-components).

While a single and simple static method looks not much different from a single and simple non-static one, it can only easily make calls to other static methods of this class and can only access static variables simply.

This blocks the advanced architectures that make no difference for the simple "hello world" but worth to consider if you want to grow up a big and complex application out of this stub.